# listview search function + and open activity

Tags: java, string, listview, android-activity, android-edittext

I have a problem that my search function doesn't work. I want to make a search function on `ListView` that when I type some text the items are filtered, and when I click on some item it goes to another activity.

**My code:**

```
package com.shady.letsdoit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    private EditText search_box;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        search_box = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        final ListView list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search);

/** <string-array name="search"> <item>@string/Android_whats_android</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_wallpaper</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_ringtone</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_lockscreen</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_langueg</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_dualsim</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_datetime</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_bluetooth</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_appmanagre</item> <item>@string/Android_perso_accounts</item> <item>@string/Android_f_m</item> <item>@string/Android_insta</item> <item>@string/Android_telgram</item> <item>@string/Android_bestapp</item> <item>@string/Android_root</item> <item>@string/Pc_whats_win</item> <item>@string/Pc_boot</item> <item>@string/Pc_nasb_win_7</item> <item>@string/Pc_nasb_win_8</item> <item>@string/Pc_nasb_win_10</item> <item>@string/Pc_win7_perso</item> <item>@string/Pc_win10_perso</item> <item>@string/Pc_win_internet_browser</item> <item>@string/Pc_win_internet_download</item> <item>@string/Pc_win_safe</item> <item>@string/Pc_win_errors_softwere</item> <item>@string/Pc_win_errors_hardwere</item> <item>@string/Pc_win_bestsoftweres</item> </string-array> **/

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.subject_name, products);
        list_view.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (selectedItem.equals("@string/Android_perso_lockscreen")) { /**each and every single of these "@string..." are an Activity for example * @string/Android_perso_wallpaper = Android_perso_wallpaper.class * that I want to open it when I click on same Item * I tried some methods but it didn't work plz help me thanks. */
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this, Android_perso_lockscreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        search_box.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                Search.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * my action bar
     **/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                Intent search = new Intent(this, Search.class);
                search.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(search);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_home:
                Intent home = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(home);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_fav:
                Intent favorite = new Intent(this, Favorits.class);
                favorite.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(favorite);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_phone:
                Intent phone = new Intent(this, phon.class);
                phone.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(phone);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_pc:
                Intent pc = new Intent(this, pc.class);
                pc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(pc);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your searching in the listview you can call the method::

```
private void setFilter(CharSequence cs) {
    String filterProducts[] = new String[]{};
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cs)) {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].contains(cs)) {
                filterProducts[j] = cs.toString();
                j++;
            }
        }
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.subject_name, filterProducts);
        list_view.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }else{
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.subject_name, products);
        list_view.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

Call it from here ::

```
 @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
          setFilter(cs);
 }
```

For that redirecting to next activity..You have to explain what you want to do and what is the problem you facing..because your code is not that much clear indication about it.